# Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on string laravel

Tags: laravel

```
$path = "public/images/";

$Image->banner_image_1 = (is_null($input['banner_image_1']))?($Image->banner_image_1) : ($input['banner_image_1']); $imageName = $Image->banner_image_1->getClientOriginalName();

$file = $Image->banner_image_1;

$file->storeAs($path, $imageName, 's3');

$url = Storage::disk('s3')->url($path.$imageName);

$Image->banner_image_1 = $imageName;
```

The error Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on string is occuring while update. How to solve this error?

Comment: The error is clear: `$Image->banner_image_1` returns a string.